# downloading binary file over REST API

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, download

I've got a *big* system where **I need to generate a PDF file. I'd like to access it via REST API** and, of course, store the file locally.

The file content depends on many parameters what the content of this file should be, i.e. time: from-to, filters, sorting and many, many more parameters; they form a JSON object which perfectly fits into POST parameters. The parameters cannot go through GET, since they're too big.

There is the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library that works perfectly fine on modern browsers. I created an [online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bLsvqm7m/2/). But when I downloaded old browsers - firefox11, firefox12, firefox15, it didn't work at all, even though I included the [Blob.js polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) - it opened a new tab with URL like: `blob:457-343457-34574567-4576456` that was unable to be saved. **I need to support many browsers, not only the new ones.**

**The question is - I've got JSON parameters object inside my SPA app - how should I design this PDF binary file download**?

I was thinking of 3 approaches:

- force browser to create a file on localhost - using FileSaver. WOrks fine for modern browsers, doesn't work for old ones
- create downloadable link. I shoot a POST to the REST API, incuding all parameters, the REST API returns something like: `{"download": "mysite.com/download/ms2h5d34h53m"}`, the response is used to display a link to the user; the user might click the link (with no AJAX) and the server-side API should just return a file like in the old times.
- not mine, but somewhere I read I could create an invisible form that shoots a POST to the server, which triggers file download (perhaps this would reduce the step with returning the `{"download": "mysite.com/download/ms2h5d34h53m"}` JSON)

I need a guidance on how to do that right.

---

I tried to create a test express.js server below. When I access `http://localhost:8081/download` directly, I see a PDF file downloaded locally. But when I try to access it via ajax/js:

[image]

then the content is fetched as binary stream:

[image]

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  var file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/example.pdf', 'binary');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=new-name.pdf');
  res.setHeader('filename', 'sample.pdf');

  res.write(file, 'binary');
  res.end();
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Comment: Maybe not any of my business... But why do you need to support such many old browsers that nobody is using this days? If you need to support all dead browser then you can forget about any javascript solution such as filesaver or any other client side solution solution, that don't even work in todays Safari. The only solution then is to use a server side solution to download things. My bet is on the hidden form submission

Comment: @Endless very good question actually. The reason is a stupid customer (hope he doesn't read it :P) that wants to support as much as possible. And of course he's not sure what he wants. So I try to gather knowledge about possible opportunities, including how much would it cost to fallback to primitive solutions. But thx for UR comment anyway.